# Oracle: search though all stored procs/triggers/other db code?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, triggers, replace

Is it possible to search through all of the programmatic objects (functions, stored procedures, triggers, etc) across multiple schemas in Oracle?

There are a number of tables that appear to be unused in my code, but I don't want to break anything by removing them without checking first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to search through object code-- you'd generally use the DBMS_METADATA package to generate the DDL for the object and then search the CLOB.  However, it doesn't sound like that's actually what you want to do.

If you are just trying to figure out whether a table is referenced by any code in your system, you would generally want to use the `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` view (or `ALL_DEPENDENCIES` or `USER_DEPENDENCIES` depending on your privileges and the scope of what you're looking for).  Something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_dependencies
 WHERE referenced_owner = 'SCOTT'
   AND referenced_name  = 'EMP'
   AND referenced_type  = 'TABLE'
```

will show you everything that depends on the `EMP` table in the `SCOTT` schema.

The only time you'd want to search code rather than looking at `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` would be when you had code that was doing dynamic SQL where the table name was hard-coded.  But that's relatively unlikely in practice.

Comment: I'm curious - will that also check to see if, for example, Procedure A depends on View B which depends on Table C?  Or would that need to be a hierarchical query?

Comment: @Adam - You'd need a hierarchial query for that.  This would only tell you that View B depends on Table C.  Oracle provides a utldtree script in %ORACLE_HOME%\rdbms\admin for this.

Comment: And to think I'd always written my own.  I had no idea utldtree existed.

Answer (score 2):

You can search the DBA_SOURCE view:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_source
 WHERE UPPER(text) LIKE '%YOUR_TABLE_NAME%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this in Toad by selecting:

Search  =>  Object Search

Answer (score 1):

If you had [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad/) you could do this built-in.  (I removed my schemas for privacy)
[image: Toad Search]

Comment: Can you share, how you reached to that dialog? Where to find option for that dialog?